# How do change focus from the address bar back to the document after CMD+L?

Tags: macos, safari

CMD-L brings focus to the Address Bar.  Is there are shortcut key for toggling back to the document of the current tab?  How else might I achieve this other than a keyboard shortcut built in to Safari?

Context:
Safari 7
OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

You can ⇥ back, or alternatively ⇧⇥ which is usually faster.

It takes me two presses of ⇧⇥ to get back from the address bar to the page: one to move to the Add to Reading List button and one to get back to the page. This may be higher if you have the back/forward buttons on the toolbar, and lower if you have Full Keyboard Access disabled in System Preferences.

You can use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to create a macro which lets you get back to the page with a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: In my safari, with 1password installed, it takes 6 shift tabs to get back to the page.  Tabbing forward, I have to press tab 5+(the number of tabs I have open). :/  I have seen Keyboard Maestro, but would rather just tab it, or click on the page then spend the money to enable one action.